# AngluarJS window directive showing View?

Tags: angularjs

I've a window directive. I like to show there a view with a controller. The only idea what comes in my mind is using IFrame. But there must be a possibility to show a entire view without loading the entire website in every window. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude)

```
<div ng-include src="'NgApp/Features/Partials/view.html'"></div>
```

Basically, you can use this on any div tag to include a partial view with it's own controller.  Configure and place the div tag where ever you wish to get the desired effect.

Note that your partial view has to come from inside your app, as opposed to an iFrame which can link to an external website.

Comment: Please remember to mark as answer if this was the solution for you.